Unable to disable specific Bluetooth profiles
In the past I have successfully used the solution for Disable "Handsfree" and "Headset" profiles for specific device?, which actually disables it for all devices but that was great for me.
However, recently I noticed these profiles have become available again, notably when opening software under Wine, my headset briefly switches to Handsfree mode.
So I looked at the logs for bluetooth.service, and I see that this option is not valid anymore?
May 03 08:34:30 khome bluetoothd[1121]: src/main.c:check_options() Unknown key Disable for group General in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf

How can I achieve a similar result? I don't ever want to use the "Handsfree" mode, no compromises necessary.
